# Timer control is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

A count down timer I'm trying to use is not working in IE, but it works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

This is the HTML of the scripts I'm including, and what I've written so far:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#counter').countdown({
            image: 'digits.png',
            startTime: '25:30'
        });            
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .desc { 
        margin: 7px 3px;
        width: 352px;
    }
    .desc div {
        float: left;
        font-family: Arial;
        width: 70px;
        margin-right: 65px;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000;
    }
    #counter {
        width: 353px;
    }
</style>
```

and this is my content in the aspx page:

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<div class="desc">
    <div>Minutes</div><div>Seconds</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this in IE 8 and IE 9. Seems to work ok.

Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .desc { margin: 7px 3px;
        width: 352px;
    }
  .desc div {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 70px;
  margin-right: 65px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  }
    #counter
    {
        width: 353px;
    }
</style>

<div id="counter"></div><div class="desc"><div>Minutes</div><div>Seconds</div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $('#counter').countdown({
             image: 'http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/img/digits.png',
             startTime: '25:30'});            

</script>
```

Make sure you have the doc type defined at the top of your html page as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```